# HttpPost Action parameter is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My model is:

```
public class Answer
{


public string AnswerText { get; set; }

public static List<Answer> GetAnswers(string[] answers)
{
    List<Answer> _answers = new List<Answer>();

    foreach (string _answer in answers)
    {
        Answer _answer1 = new Answer()
        {
            AnswerText = _answer
        };

        _answers.Add(_answer1);
    }

    return _answers;
}
}

public class Question
{
    [Required]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionAnswerModel
{
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Question Question { get; set; }
```

My controller is:

```
        [HttpPost]
```

//this _model is null when doing post by changing the view's textbox

```
        public ActionResult A(QuestionAnswerModel _model)
        {

           QuestionAnswerModel _questionanswerModel = new QuestionAnswerModel();
//            _questionanswerModel.Answers = Answer.GetAnswers(_response.GetAnswerResult);

            _questionanswerModel.Question = new Question();

            return View(_questionanswerModel);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult A(string question)
        {

            QuestionAnswerModel _questionanswerModel = new QuestionAnswerModel();
//            _questionanswerModel.Answers = Answer.GetAnswers(_response.GetAnswerResult);

            _questionanswerModel.Question = new Question() {
                QuestionText = question
            };

            return View(_questionanswerModel);
        }
```

My view is:

```
@model ProjectnameSample.Models.QuestionAnswerModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "A";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>A</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>QuestionAnswerModel</legend>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Question.QuestionText)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I have HttpPost and HttpGet for an Action, but when I change the textbox, the textbox text is not coming through the parameter and the Model is null including `Question` and `Answers` in `QuestionAnswerModel`

I have a 2 models for a view. the answer and the question.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, to my mind:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult A(QuestionAnswerModel _model)
        {
         var question = _model.Question;
         var answers = db.Answers.Where(g=>g.questionID == question.ID).ToList() // Or question.Answers.ToList() or other selector

 var model = new QuestionAnswerModel
{
Answers = answers,
Question = question   
};
            return View(model);
        }
```

You get null, because of trying to get `Question` proprety of `_questionanswerModel`, which is new instance. Instead you need to get it from `_model`, which you received from form.